# Force encoding on ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I'm attempting to save the params from PayPal's IPN so they can be accessed later and used for cross reference.

Simple little bit of code that saves it in the `paypal_log` column:

`@order.paypal_log = params.to_json`

Worked fine, pushed to production and still was working fine. Investigating the logs for another issue, I came across the following line:

`Completed 500 Internal Server 
JSON::GeneratorError (source sequence is illegal/malformed utf-8):`

The line it points to is the above `params.to_json`

After looking around I discovered `force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")`
[(source)](https://gist.github.com/polimorfico/4074902)

I changed the line to `params.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8").to_json` and ran my tests with a error of:

`` undefined method `force_encoding' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x000000073357f0> ``

This makes me thing that for some reason, you can't parse the whole params variable, only a hash. Any possible solution for forcing encoding for all params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can iterate over each param and force the encoding.

```
params.each { |k, v| params[k] = v.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8') }
```